# Linux terminal one-liner command to evaluate the response of an HTTP request

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm guessing this is a very simple question, sorry about that.

I need to execute a command based on the response of an HTTP request. It's just that it has to be a single line of command and no bash script (by that I mean a separate bash script file).

Here's a more concrete example. I have a local API that returns an integer if it is up and running:

```
$ curl -s http://localhost
1
```

Of course, for whatever reason the server might be down in which case the above command will return an empty string. Or it might be up but it returns `0`. In either of these two cases, I need to execute a command to mitigate this situation (if you are interested, I'll be executing `exit(1)`). Otherwise, if the API returns `1` or a larger number, I don't need to do anything.

Can someone please help me come up with a one-liner for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use command substitution to get the returned value as a string, then you can compare it inside the `test` command.

Here's a one-liner, but it only recognizes `1` as a valid answer:

```
[ "$(curl -s http://localhost)" = "1" ] || exit 1
```

Here's one that allows any value at least 1 as valid, but I can't write it as a one-liner.

```
var=$(curl -s http://localhost)
if [ -z "$var" ] || [ "$var" -eq 0 ]
then exit 1
fi
```

I don't know how to do this as a one-liner, because it needs to do two different tests on the result: a string test to check for an empty result, and a numeric test for `0`. That requires assigning to a variable or doing repeated `curl` requests.

Comment: Thanks but how about `2` or any larger number? Your solution exits for them while it shouldn't.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: `if the API returns 1 or a larger number, I don't need to do anything.`

Comment: I misread that. This is harder in a one-liner, because you can't do a numeric comparison with the empty string that will be returned if there's no response. You need to assign the output of the command to a variable, then you can do multiple tests on that variable.

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner?

Comment: That's beside the point. Thanks. I guess I'll change the API to return `0` or `1` only then. I'll give you the point but I think you understand why I cannot approve it as an answer.

Comment: I suggest please keep that old one as well. Granted that it was not the answer but at least it was a one-liner.

Comment: I added back the original.